# Why do i get the "ORA-06512" error and how do i remove it?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_week_day
BEFORE 
    INSERT OR UPDATE OR  DELETE
ON emp
BEGIN 
    IF (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY') = 'SAT' OR TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY') = 'SUN') 
         THEN 
         raise_application_error(-20000,'User: ' ||user ||' May not change employee table during the weekend.'); 
       else
        dbms_output.put_line('Today is not Weekend, Let us Work');
        END IF; 
END;
/

UPDATE emp
SET sal = 32000
WHERE empno= 101;
```

I get the following error

> Trigger created.
>
> ORA-20000: User: APEX_PUBLIC_USER May not change employee table during the weekend.
> ORA-06512: at "SQL_XDFWSAJBEIBDLNRPNGQWTGKQO.TRG_WEEK_DAY", line 5
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Edit 1: I need to create a trigger on emp table before insert update or delete command is done on emp table on weekend.
i understand the ORA-20000: error

but I don't understand how to remove the ORA-06512: and what is it about...
Understanding the below comments I get that it is because of unhandled exceptions...is there a way to resolve it? in this code

Thank everyone for the help.

Comment: You understand why you get the first error, right? (That's exactly what you **wanted** to do.) And you are only asking about the further error, ORA-06512? If so: That error is thrown when your program (in this case: the trigger) throws an error but does not handle it. You don't need to handle it - what you got as an error stack is fine. But you CAN handle it if you like - in the `exception` section (which you don't have now).

Comment: As a side observation on your ELSE condition .... dbms_output does not write to the screen (pl/sql has no access to the client's input or output devices) and only writes to an internal buffer, to be processed (or ignored) by the client when control returns to the client.  Thus, use of dbms_output for anything other than debugging is not a good idea.

Comment: [ORA-06512](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e4100.htm#1656): **Cause**: Backtrace message as the stack is unwound by unhandled exceptions. **Action**: Fix the problem causing the exception or write an exception handler for this condition. Or you may need to contact your application administrator or database administrator.

Comment: @astentx - it would have been simpler to post a link to the source of what you posted, instead of copying it and pasting here (without crediting your source). Moreover, in this case the first part of the solution is obviously not applicable: the OP specifically WANTS to throw an error - that's the only purpose for the trigger in the first place. So "fixing the problem causing the exception" does not apply.

Comment: In passing, we had a serious production issue recently caused by code very similar to `IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY') = 'SAT' OR TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DY') = 'SUN'` (the user was running it from France). I'd advise including the nls_language every time, just in case.

Comment: @mathguy There's a link to the documentation with this description in my comment. I'm absolutely convinced that documentation is the first place to look at. The first solution is obviously not applicable, but the second one is: exception should be handled by the surrounding code (PL/SQL or external program). "This is a backtrace" answers for "why" (and is quite clear). "How to remove it" is not a clear question for me: remove from where? From the output to something? Since Apex is PL/SQL backed, the second solution is the answer. Can you please clarify what was wrong in my comment?

Comment: @astentx - apologies, didn't notice the link at the beginning of the comment (saw it just as a title, didn't notice it was a link). The rest is not "wrong" - I just noted for clarity that in the OP's question, "fixing the problem that caused the exception" is exactly the opposite of what the task was, which was to throw an exception when [.....]

Comment: @mathguy It was my best attempt to provide full information from the docs along with the link, because links may not be followed (for whatever reason). Exception handling at the application side is the way to "fix". Of course, not by "removing" intentionally introduced exception. Thank you for clarification.